# select column names that start with x

Tags: mysql, wildcard

Im trying to select all column names from a mysql table that start with pweb and then have an integer.

This works for all column names:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='producten';
```

But this does not work unfortunately, how can I make this happen?

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='producten' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE `pweb`;
```

Thanks!

Comment: By does not work do you mean the query doesn't fire at all or do you mean that it doesn't return any results?

Comment: `LIKE \`pweb\`` should be `LIKE 'pweb%'`. String literals aren't back ticked.

Comment: Your question needs to be clarified - do you mean pweb1, pweb2, pweb3 for example ? Or do you mean pweb and the column has a value of integer. You have 2 answers below for each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='producten' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE 'pweb%'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
```

Comment: this did the trick, thank you, I did not know the % had to be added, LIKE has worked without for me in other instances.

Answer (score 3):

you have to add the % after pweb.

so the sql statement select all column_name which begins with pweb******

Note: **** means other caracteres

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA, COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='producten' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'pweb%';
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='producten' 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'pweb%'
AND DATA_TYPE = 'int'
```